# Varrer um ArrayList de objetos e verificar um atributo de um objeto passado como parâmetro com um do ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Sou iniciante em Java e meu professor passou uma lista de exercícios para praticar, em uma questão eu preciso criar um sistema que cadastra um usuário apenas se o email dele não tiver sido cadastrado antes.

Uma parte da classe Usuário é assim (é abstrata pois existem vários tipos de usuário):

```
public abstract class Usuario {
    private String email;
    private String nomeCompleto;
    private LocalDate dataNascimento;    

    public Usuario(String email, String nomeCompleto, LocalDate dataNascimento) {
        this.email = email;
        this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
```

Eu criei um repositório para "cadastrar" os usuários em um ArrayList, que ficou assim:

```
public class RepositorioUsuario {
    private ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    public void cadastrarUsuario(Usuario u) {
        for (Usuario a : this.usuarios) {
            if (u.getEmail().equals(a.getEmail())) {
                usuarios.add(u);
            }
        }
    }
```

A parte que não funciona de jeito nenhum é essa, especificamente a verificação.

```
for (Usuario a : this.usuarios) {
            if (u.getEmail().equals(a.getEmail())) {
                usuarios.add(u);
            }
        }
```

Se eu tirar o for e o if, o usuário é adicionado sem problemas (criei um método para listar eles).

Minha pergunta é, porque do jeito que eu fiz não está funcionando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu *loop* percorre a lista de usuários e verifica se o email destes é igual ao email do usuário que você quer cadastrar. Como a lista começa vazia, não tem nenhum usuário, então ele nem sequer entra no `for`, e por isso nunca cadastrará nenhum usuário.

Aliás, não faz sentido cadastrar um usuário somente se já existir outro usuário com um email igual. Geralmente é o contrário: se o email do usuário a ser cadastrado já existe, então eu não cadastro. Provavelmente o que você quer é algo assim:

```
public class RepositorioUsuario {

    private ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    public void cadastrarUsuario(Usuario novoUsuario) {
        if (existe(novoUsuario)) {
            System.out.println("Já existe um usuário com o email " + novoUsuario.getEmail() + " cadastrado");
        } else {
            usuarios.add(novoUsuario);
        }
    }

    // verificar se o usuário já existe
    private boolean existe(Usuario novoUsuario) {
        for (Usuario user : this.usuarios) {
            if (user.getEmail().equals(novoUsuario.getEmail())) {
                return true; // já existe usuário com este email
            }
        }
        return false; // se chegou até aqui, é porque o email ainda não existe
    }
}
```

Primeiro você verifica se já existe um usuário com o mesmo email. Para isso você precisa percorrer toda a lista, mas veja que, assim que um usuário com o mesmo email é encontrado, eu já posso retornar `true` (o `return true` interrompe o *loop*). Se eu percorrer todos os usuários e não encontrar outro com o mesmo email, aí eu retorno `false` (pois eu garanti que não existe outro usuário com o mesmo email).

Por fim, eu adiciono o usuário na lista somente se este ainda não existir.